Are each of the 7 Chakras more likely to open at certain ages for spiritual aspirants?
According to this site, there're ages best suited for awakening various Chakras starting from the Muladhara upto the Sahasrara.
For example, Heart Chakra develops best between the ages of 21-28, Agya Chakra at the age of 42, and the Sahasrara Chakra at age 49.
Is this directly or indirectly mentioned in any of the scriptures of Tantra, etc.?

Age is not a factor for awakening the chakras. If it was, then it would be a bit easier to open the chakras for each and everyone as everyone will pass through that age at a certain time.
Besides that, the chakras are more like energy points which activate as per one's level of consciousness.
